# Javaでキーボード入力し変数を代入

Tags: java

Java でキーボードから整数値を入力し、それを変数に代入したい。
テストの点数を入力し、点数ごとに違う文書を表示させるコードを書きたいです。

```
public class main{
  public static void main (String[] args){

    int input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

  }

  public static void point(){
    if (点数が100点){
      System.out.println(文章は未定);
    } else if (70点から99点){
      System.out.println();
    } else {
      System.out.println("頑張りましょう");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 本題とは関係ありませんが、`String[]` と書くべきところが `String［］` になっていたので直しました。Markdown の関係で消えるのを阻止されたのだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

> Java でキーボードから整数値を入力し、それを変数に代入したい。

できてます。
変数`input`にキーボードから入力した整数値が代入されています。
下記のように`System.out.println`で`input`の内容を表示すれば、代入されていることが分かります。

```
int input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
System.out.println("inputに入っている値は'" + input + "'です。");
```

> テストの点数を入力し、点数ごとに違う文書を表示させるコードを書きたいです。

点数ごとに違う文書を表示させるには`point`メソッドに引数を渡すと良いでしょう。
引数で渡すことではじめて`input`の値をif文で評価することができます。

下記のサンプルコードでは`if (点数が100点)`のような文章によるロジックがコンパイルエラーにならないよう、強引にコンパイルを通す工夫をしています。

```
public class main {

    static final Boolean 点数が100点 = false;
    static final Boolean _70点から99点 = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        System.out.println("inputに入っている値は'" + input + "'です。");
        checkPoint(input);
        point();
    }

    public static void point() {
        if (点数が100点) {
            System.out.println("文章は未定");
        } else if (_70点から99点) {
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println("頑張りましょう");
        }
    }

    /**
     * if文を使わずに頑張るコードサンプル
     * @param p 引数とはこのように使うのだ
     */
    private static void checkPoint(int p)
    {
        int d = (int)(p / 10);
        String s;
        switch(d) {
            case 10: s = "文章は未定"; break;
            case 9: case 8: case 7: s = "???"; break;
            default: s = "頑張りましょう"; break;
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

変数と"文字列"の差異、if文の使い方、`==`の使い方、`&&`の使い方はここまでのテキストで提示されていたはずなので、それを読み解けば`checkPoint`メソッドを参考にして`point`メソッドの引数に`input`の値を送り、点数ごとに違う文書を表示させられます。

頑張ってください。